# Rails 3: Change link based on log ins status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, erb

I would like to change where the logo in my app links to based on the users status (logged in or not).

If the user is logged in I would like it to link to their profile page (users/show). If not logged in then to root_path.

I have this setup using a helper:

View:

```
<%= link_to logo, root_path %>
```

Helper:

```
  def logo
    logo = image_tag("rlogo.png", alt: "Sample App")
  end
```

Thanks

Comment: FYI, in your helper, there's no reason to set a `logo` variable. You can just do `image_tag("rlogo.png", alt: "Sample App")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ternary solution Matzi suggested would certainly work, but another option would be to modify your helper to set up the logo and link, something like this (where `current_user` is a method that returns a `User` instance for the logged in user):

```
def logo_link
  destination = current_user.present? ? current_user : root_path
  link_to image_tag("rlogo.png", alt: "Sample App"), destination
end
```

Then, in your view, just include

```
<%= logo_link %>
```

You could also use your existing `logo` helper inside the `logo_link` helper, if it's something you'll still want outside to use of that context.

Answer (score 0):

Use C-like conditional expression in view:

```
<%= link_to logo, (is_logged ? profile_path : root_path) %>
```